# How to display images in sequence one after another in same window location in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have 2 images in a folder named as 1.jgp , 2.jpg. I want to write a python code to display all the images one after another in the same location of the pane after 2 second delay.
I have tried the following code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def main():
    imgPath="/home/unikx/1_project/codes/batman.jpg"
    imgPath2="/home/unikx/1_project/codes/batman2.jpg"
    img1=cv2.imread(imgPath,1)
    img2=cv2.imread(imgPath2,1)

    img1=cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img2=cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    plt.imshow(img1)
    plt.title("Image 1")
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show(block=False)
    time.sleep(2)
    plt.close()

    plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    plt.imshow(img2)
    plt.title("Image 2")
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show(block=False)
    time.sleep(2)
    plt.close()


    plt.imshow(img1)
    plt.title("Again Image 1")
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(2)
    plt.close()

import matplotlib 
matplotlib.pyplot.close("all")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

But this code displays 1.jpg in a window then once I close it, it displays the 2.jpg. I want image 1 to display then image 2 after 2 second in that  same window.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def main():
    imgPath="download.jpeg"
    imgPath2="cat.0.jpg"
    img1=cv2.imread(imgPath,1)
    img2=cv2.imread(imgPath2,1)

    img1=cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img2=cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    plt.subplot(1,1,1)

    plt.imshow(img1)

    plt.title("Image 1.jpg")
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show(block=False)
    time.sleep(3)
    plt.close()
    plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    plt.imshow(img2)
    plt.title("Image 2.jpg")
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Just add `block=False` in the `plt.show()`. It should work. Also you need to close the first `plt` to show the next one in the same window.

Comment: I have made the suggested changes, but the plt.show(block=False) statement doesnt display the image instead it gives a black screen for 3 seconds and then closes the window and then pop the 2nd new image correctly.

Comment: are you sure, you put the correct path of the first image?

Comment: Yes, the moment I remove the block=False, it shows the image but I have to close the window to display for the 2nd image to display. Now I tried this as image 1 2 1, but still 1 2 black and last 1 is displayed.

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.show(*args, **kw)`
Display a figure. When running in ipython with its pylab mode, display all figures and return to the ipython prompt.

In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until the figures have been closed; in interactive mode it has no effect unless figures were created prior to a change from non-interactive to interactive mode (not recommended). In that case it displays the figures but does not block.

A single experimental keyword argument, block, may be set to True or False to override the blocking behavior described above.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show And actually it's working with me.

Comment: Can you please paste the code which worked for you. Sorry, I am begginer in Python and confused with interactive/non-interactive mode stuff. I saw the link but seems like its a bit heavy for me to understand.

Comment: The above answer is the exact code which works fine for me? Are you in Ipython or are you running your code from the terminal?

Comment: I have written the code in Sublime and running it in the terminal.

Comment: Ok, which version of python and matplotlib?

Comment: Can you add `import matplotlib 
matplotlib.pyplot.close("all")` before the main function?

Comment: Added
`
def main():
...........code above...........
import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot.close("all")

if __name__=="__main__":
 main()
`
Still the same problem.

Comment: I tried in the iPython, it display the images 1 then 2 correctly below one after another, but I have to play many such images 100 images in a window. Any suggessions for that.

Comment: basically, you plot one, close and plot another, probably in a loop. Did the first one closed before showing the second one in Ipython?

Comment: No, it remained. Displayed one after another.

Comment: what version of matplotlib is it? And also can you please show me your code, the updated one?

Comment: I am using Matplotlib 2.2.2 and I have updated the code in the question itself.

Comment: Ok, just to confirm, are you using windows system?

Comment: No, its Ubuntu 18.04